# ReactJS repo not building when deploying

Tags: reactjs, netlify

Basically, there is an existing web app built in ReactJS that the developer no longer maintains, but has a public GitHub repo for the app. I was hoping I could simply clone the repo and deploy it to Netlify to get a working clone of the app that I could then make edits to (I have the developer's permission for this), but when I attempt to do this, the web app doesn't appear to build, as the webpage is blank except for the site name and favicon. This is without making any edits to the production code that is already successfully deployed elsewhere. I have very little experience with React (and web development in general), so would really appreciate any help in troubleshooting this. Is there something else I need to do to get my fork of the repo to build properly when deploying? All I'm trying to do at the moment is successfully publish a clone of the existing app before I can begin making updates.

Some relevant links in case they are useful:
Original GitHub repo: https://github.com/Huuums/baseball-superstars-deckbuilder
Existing (working) web app: https://basu2020-deckbuilder.netlify.app/
My fork of the GitHub repo: https://github.com/ryangillman/baseball-superstars-deckbuilder
My (not working) deployed app: https://basuclone.netlify.app/

Let me know if anything else is needed from me. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

This app uses api under the hood and requires some information from the database (Firebase database).

Error from the browser console:

```
Your API key is invalid, please check you have copied it correctly.
```

Required API key, from the *https://github.com/ryangillman/baseball-superstars-deckbuilder/blob/master/src/firebase.js* file:

```
apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
```

As I understand, you can't use this code without database.